# Writing a toUpper function for unicode letters

Tags: string, unicode, go

From here http://blog.golang.org/slices (it's right before the Capacity section)

```
type path []byte

func (p path) ToUpper() {
    for i, b := range p {
        if 'a' <= b && b <= 'z' {
            p[i] = b + 'A' - 'a'
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    pathName := path("/usr/bin/tso")
    pathName.ToUpper()
    string1 := string(pathName)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string1)
}
```

Was reading on slices and stuff in golang. This is a function to convert ascii characters. How would you go about turning this function to handle unicode as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `rune` when you use unicode. The `unicode` package in golang has a toUpper function.

```
package main

import (
    "unicode"
    "fmt"
)

type path []rune

func (p path) ToUpper() {
    for i, b := range p {
        p[i] = unicode.ToUpper(b)
    }
}

func main() {
    pathName := path("/usr/bin/tso")
    pathName.ToUpper()
    string1 := string(pathName)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string1)
}
```

in the playground:
[example](https://play.golang.org/p/yIbjkde2rY)

Comment: Does it support multi-character replacements like `ß` → `SS`?

Comment: Or just use (or look at the source for) `strings.ToUpper`. This was listed as an "Advanced exercise" in the document you link to so asking for an answer is like asking someone else to do your homework for you. :)

Comment: @dan04 it didn't work in the playground so guess not :/

Comment: @dan04 See the follow up blog post: [Text normalization in Go](https://blog.golang.org/normalization) for more about Unicode and Go. But the short answer is `unicode.ToUpper` takes a rune and returns a rune so it can't possibly convert one rune to several.

Comment: @Dave C Very new to the Go language. Not much experience, I just learnt about runes and this stuff now. I guess I could have probably just figured it out myself but I thought they wanted me to implement a actual function to do it all though itself, without the library. But I guess not, that would be really hard.

Comment: @aubble, sortof, the actual `strings.ToUpper` function is literally just `func ToUpper(s string) string { return Map(unicode.ToUpper, s) }`. The `strings.Map` function isn't bad though. The standard packages are a good place to look for learning idiomatic Go that does things well (mostly, there is some cruft in the corners).

Comment: @dan04 I think it converts ß to ẞ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strings.Map` to apply a function to each rune of a string, returning the mapped string. [Playground link to this code:](https://play.golang.org/p/5Fm3Tc7RjC)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    pathName := strings.Map(unicode.ToUpper, "/usr/bin/tso")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", pathName)
}
```